# Bullet Physics, CMake fails to build project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, cmake, bulletphysics

I'm trying to use CMake to build the Bullet Physics 3 source code for Visual Studio 2012.

I've tried using the CMake GUI to build the projects and the command line version. Each time I get a set of vcxproj and sln files:

- project.sln
- ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj
- ALL_BUILD.vcxproj
- BulletCollision.vcxproj
- BulletDynamics.vcxproj
- BulletSoftBody.vcxproj
- LinearMath.vcxproj

This is not what I expected. The documentation here: says there should be BULLET_PHYSICS.sln that does not appear.

Furthermore when I try to import the projects into Visual Studio and do a build all of the #include lines fail. They're trying to find the files originally referenced in the Bullet Physics source directory and failing rather than looking the the current Visual Studio project folder where I've put the CMake built output. I tried manually editing all the project and solution files which contained many occurrences of the original source path and not my new build directory but this made no difference.

Why is CMake failing to build Bullet Physics properly?

Comment: Looks like it is instead `project.sln`.

Comment: ***I try to import the projects into Visual Studio and do a build all of the #include lines fail.*** When you configured in cmake-gui was anything listed as NOT_FOUND. Turn on the show advanced checkbox in the cmake-gui.

Comment: Nothing is listed as NOT_FOUND but when comparing the list of Cmake options to those in this tutorial: http://bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/Creating_a_project_from_scratch#Creating_a_project_from_scratch_using_Visual_Studio_.28any_version.29 I find that I have practically none of those options. I have about 30 CMAKE specific options but none that don't start with the word CMAKE.

Comment: Did you click the advanced checkbox in cmake-gui. The directions are for an old version of cmake.

Comment: I now think your problem is at the `Additional Include Directories` step. Make sure the files you are including are in the folder you added to ` Additional Include Directories`.